# Procedure too large error when applying Macro. How can I make it smaller?

Tags: excel

So, I want certain columns to show color patterns for their values. From columns A to CD, however I can't select them all, otherwise my sheet will be messed up because the average will be taken from values from all columns and I need it to be calculated individually. My solution? To copy the code from one column and just paste it again and replace for the next column such as code below:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
...
```

And it goes on and on....

When I tried to run it, I get an error saying "Procedure too large". How can I simplify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
Dim c as Range, fc As ColorScale

For Each c in Range("A1:CD1").Cells

    Set fc = c.EntireColumn.FormatConditions.AddColorScale( _
                                               ColorScaleType:=3)
    fc.SetFirstPriority
    fc.ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With fc.ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    fc.ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
    fc.ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With fc.ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    fc.ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With fc.ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

Next c
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for :)